# What is mean average error?

Tags: error, mae

I saw that in some articles but I couldn't find any definition. Its unit is in the following form:

**MAE/mean(MAE)**

Comment: I couldn’t make sense of the expression, can you share the articles?

Comment: Here it is : https://journals.aps.org/prmaterials/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.2.034005

Comment: MAE usually stands for Mean Absolute Error. $MAE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n | y_i  - \hat{y}_i |$

Comment: MAE is already a mean, so mean(MAE)=MAE unless they are using some unorthodox deductions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the paper you linked, they are simply defining the 'normalized' mean average error (MAE), which is the paper's approach to allowing the reader to more easily understand how the MAEs differ across the '12 methods' they explore (I did not read the paper carefully, so I don't know what that exactly means). MAE is indeed defined as is standard, and as mentioned in the comments.

As the the start of Section III (Results) of the paper you linked defines it, the 'normalized MAE' for method $j$ is
$$\frac{MAE(j)}{\frac{1}{12}\sum_{i=1}^12 MAE(i)}$$
where again, the $12$ is cause of their 12 methods they are comparing, which allows them to easily plot all the MAEs together in Figure 1, allowing you to compare the methods. If the normalized MAE for $j$ is greater than $1$, then it's MAE is larger than the average MAE of their methods, and so on...